# How to use @Input in <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new in angular 4. I found out that there is a way in angular to pass data from the parent component to the child component using @Input just like following:

`<child [dataToPass]="test"></child>`

My question is how to do the same thing using a router. In the router, there is no child definition like `<child></child>`; it only has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, so how do I pass data using @Input?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use a [**shared service**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) or use [**Ngrx**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx).

> Component added by the router is added as sibling to
>    and does not replace it

Answer (score -1):

What you want to achieve is to prefetching data from component to another when transferring via router.
I highly suggest using a resolver to load the data as explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data).

This will allow you to not only pass data via the router but also will the second component/page wait till the data is fetched so you don't run in a case of "my site is loaded but no data is displayed" ;) if you need further help with the implementation feel free to comment on this and share some code in your question.